# Ordering joins and its limit in database systems these days

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization

in http://www.cs.uoi.gr/~pitoura/grdb01/ioannidis.pdf I have read that:

> In fact, many modern systems place a limit on the size of queries that
>   can be submitted (usually around fteen joins), because for larger
>   queries the optimizer crashes due to its very high memory
>   requirements. Nevertheless, most queries seen in practice involve less
>   than ten joins, and the algorithm has proved to be very eective in
>   such contexts.

Is it  true for this time?
For me, it seems to be very strange that we can only join 15 relations.
Moreover, contemporary databases does still use dynamic algorithm for join ordering?

Comment: This is definitely not true for Postgres, Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not true.  You must have a very old source.  The normal limit on queries, as far as I encounter, is either on the total length of the query or on the number of items in an `IN` list.

I have personally generated queries that are over 100k in size -- although I don't recall the number of joins.

For any given database, you can check if there are such limits.  I can add that the optimizer takes short-cuts when there are a lot of joins -- and without indexes, your queries might be inefficient.

Comment: What are shtoc-uts?

Comment: I have no idea.